# Why isn't this MCP6004 op amp operating rail to rail?

Tags: operational-amplifier

This is the op amp I used:

[image]

To test it, I used it for a noninverting amplifier where I had a potentiometer as the feedback resistor. Everything worked fine except the output was capped at around 3.65 V when I had a VDD of 5 V and VSS of 0 V.

Below is an image of a page from the datasheet. In the red circle it says that I should have no more than 4.975 V (5-0.025) but that's not the case.

[image]

Is something wrong with my op amp?

I bought 10 of these MCP6004 from Aliexpress (around 4 €.) Perhaps I got bad quality ones/counterfeits.

One of them just maintains the same output voltage no matter what value the potentiometer is and it gets hot a lot. I think that one is broken.

Here is the circuit:

[image]

The feedback resistor is a 10 kΩ potentiometer, the input voltage is 0.68 V and the other resistor value is 1 kΩ. I'm using an ESP32 microcontroller.

The circuit above is doing the same as the image below:

[image]

It just has one more connection.  I'm also taking the output of the op amp and connecting it to the microcontroller to see its voltage in the Arduino IDE. The cables that show one terminal is where I use a multimeter to measure its voltage

Comment: Please draw the circuit, don't make us guess.

Comment: Could easily be counterfeits. Maybe something like a rebranded LM324.

Comment: Aliexpress is a good source of counterfeits, I'm afraid. Try Mouser or Digikey next time.

Comment: The problem is that you bought them from Aliexpress.

Comment: `mantains the same output voltage no matter what value the potentiometer is` ... what potentiometer?

Comment: _"i used it for a noninverting amplifier where i had a potentiometer as the feedback resistor."_ - Please show us the circuit.

Comment: How much load you had? What's the potentiometer resistance? The datasheet parameter is measured with 0.5v overdrive, did you use the same conditions as the datasheet measurements?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/diypedals/comments/fa2z6d/are_your_opamps_fake_tested/ "Literally every dip opamp I have tested from China (AliExpress) turned out to be a relabeled lm358/lm324 :("

Comment: So i already added the circuit. I used a 10kohm potentiometer and dont have any load. The input voltage is 0.68V.

Comment: Schematic missing. VTC.

Answer (score 2):

That IC looks upside down, though it's difficult to see. I think I see the pin 1 marker (a small dimple) at the top right, and the package's divot on the right side.

In that orientation you would have Vdd connected to pin 11, and Vss to pin 4, which is the wrong way round.